# Debug Assertion fail using delete[]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I've looked through many similar questions, but all of them said to do what I am doing.
I have a char** variable that is basically just an array of strings and I'm just trying to free the memory.

```
CStringArray::~CStringArray() {
    delete[] eachSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        delete[] data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
}
```

I always get a Debug Assertion Failed error when this runs.

This is how data is defined.

```
CStringArray::CStringArray(vector<string> strings) {
    size = strings.size() + 1;
    data = new char* [size];
    // Set last element to null.
    data[size - 1] = NULL;
    // Convert each string to a cstring.
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        data[i] = (char*) strings.at(i).c_str();
    }
}
```

Comment: pointers and arrays are different. how is `data` defined?

Comment: I updated the question to have how data is defined. It is declared as a char** variable.

Comment: @Lvl1Lasagna I don't understand why you are using `CStringArray` when you are already using `std::vector<std::string>`.  What is the purpose of `CStringArray`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, it does also seem rather strange to me. This is a program for my Operating Systems class and my professor requested we change the typing. I think it may be for passing to a C program using the cmd in the future.

Comment: Then `std::vector<char *>` would, at the very least, reduce one level of complexity instead of using `CStringArray`.

Comment: Why are you +1'ing `size`? You'll also need to copy each c-string onto the heap.

Comment: It would be considerably simpler if `CStringArray` just had a `vector<string>` member to store the strings

Comment: @Rafael I need to have a NULL char* at the end of the array that's why I +1 to the size.

Comment: @M.M Oh definitely, but the whole point of this class is to convert from that vector<string> to a char**.

Comment: If you're storing `size` as a class member then there is no need to have the last element be null,  since you always know how many you actually have due to the size.

Comment: @M.M I do not see the point in having the last element be NULL either, but my professor requested this as a function of the array.

Answer (score 3):

In your constructor:

```
CStringArray::CStringArray(vector<string> strings)
```

`strings`, here, is a parameter to this constructor. When the constructor returns, the `strings` vector gets destroyed. It becomes no more. It ceases to exist. It joins the choir invisible. It becomes an ex-parameter. That's how all parameters, to all functions, including constructors, work. They are objects of their own, with their own life, that comes to a natural end when their function returns. Whatever was in this vector, it will be completely gone when the constructor returns.

```
data[i] = (char*) strings.at(i).c_str();
```

`c_str()` is a pointer to a `string`'s internal buffer. When the string goes away and gets destroyed, ***or gets modified***, the pointer that's returned by `c_str()` here will no longer valid, and any attempt to use it becomes undefined behavior.

This is precisely why `c_str()` returns a `const`, and why you had to explicitly cast it to a `char *` to make a compiler error go away. C++ errors tell you there's a real problem with the code, and attempts to fix compiler errors by explicit casting rarely is the right thing to do, and almost always ends up creating more problems than it solves. A pointer to something that's `const` is a warning sign: do not touch. You can't touch this. And you can't do anything else except to read what's in there, at this fleeting point in time. And nothing more. But that's not the end of the problems here; in addition, in the destructor:

```
    delete[] data[i];
```

You can only `delete` what was `new`ed. This is a hard rule, there is no exception to it. `data[i]` was never `new`ed, it was a `c_str()` pointer (forcibly casted) to a `string`'s internal buffer. Even if that pointer was still valid (it's not because, remember, that parameter, where this `c_str()` came from, no longer exists), this `delete` will still be invalid.

In conclusion: there are several fundamental problems here with the shown constructor and destructor code, and you will need to address all of these issues.

Comment: You are truly my savior. Thank you so much.